# how FocusEvent input field and use button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I have multiple text fields and buttons. When a text field is selected, text should be added to it when a button is pressed but nothing is inserted with bellow code. what i have missed.
thanks for your help.

```
    public class ButtonExample_Extended extends JFrame implements  ActionListener {
    public JPanel createContentPane (){
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
    buttonPanel.setLocation(10, 50);
    buttonPanel.setSize(1370, 770);
    totalGUI.add(buttonPanel);

    B9 = new JButton("9");
    B9.setLocation(1190, 570);
    B9.setSize(50, 50);
    B9.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(B9);

    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordField.setLocation(900,565);
    passwordField.setSize(120,30);
    buttonPanel.add(passwordField);
    }

  private JTextComponent selectedTextField;

    // TextFields onFocus event
    private void a33FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        selectedTextField = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
    }

    // action for button

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == B9)
        selectedTextField.setText( selectedTextField.getText() + "9" );


    }
    }
```

with above code i expected to insert 9 to textPasswordField but it doesn't.

Comment: Does your class implement `ActionListener`?. You should show a complete running code.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: try selectedTextField.setEnabled(true)

Comment: @peeskillet  yes of course it implemented ActionListener , i also edited above code and now declaration of the class line is written

Comment: @AJ there is no method available name setEnabled for the selectedTextField!

Comment: I say SCCEE. Can't tell with incomplete code. Just post your complete running code so someone can test it out. Or better yet http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: JTextComponet have setEnabled function check it here http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/api/com/sun/java/swing/text/JTextComponent.html

Comment: unrlated: a) don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive task of the LayoutManager b) Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that

```
private void a33FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    selectedTextField = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
}
```

is ever called? I guess your class should implement FocusListener and add something like

```
passwordField.addFocusListener(this);

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    selectedTextField = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    selectedTextField = null;
}
```

This is a sample code of what you should do (if I understood you correctly), note that at first you need to set cursor to the password field and after that the button will work, however you can see the bad side of this approach in the focusLost method

```
public class Snippet implements ActionListener, FocusListener {
public JFrame totalGUI = new JFrame();
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JButton B9;

public Snippet() {
    createContentPane();
}

public void createContentPane() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    B9 = new JButton("9");
    B9.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(B9);

    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordField.setSize(120, 30);
    passwordField.addFocusListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(passwordField);

    totalGUI.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
    totalGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    totalGUI.pack();
}

private JTextComponent selectedTextField;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() == B9 && selectedTextField != null)
        selectedTextField.setText(selectedTextField.getText() + "9");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Snippet().totalGUI.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() instanceof JTextComponent)
        selectedTextField = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    // when you push the button the text field will lose focus
    // selectedTextField = null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a FocusListener and ActionListener together. This assumes that events will be fired in a certain order, that is first the focusGained and then the actionPerformed. Swing provides no guarantees about the order of the events.

Instead you can extend `TextAction`. TextAction is a special Action used be Swing components because it tracks the last component that had focus. For example to create an Action that selects all the text you can do:

```
class SelectAll extends TextAction
{
    public SelectAll()
    {
        super("Select All");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
        component.selectAll();
        component.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

Then to use the Action you would do:

```
b9.addActionListener( new SelectAll() );
```